# Define multiple routes for Gesdinet Refresh Token authorization

Tags: authentication, symfony, token, admin, refresh-token

We have a Symfony project.
There are two parts - admin and user side of an application.
We separated API for these parts, both in a Controller structure and in Security configuration.
We use Gesdinet bundle to refresh user authorization by a refresh token. I need to refresh user token and admin tokens separately, cause they have different firewalls for authorization.
There is a stopper for this task. gesdinet_jwt_refresh_token.yaml could include only one path or a firewall to handle.

We have this firewall set up for this need:
        `refresh: pattern: ^/api/v1/auth/refresh provider: app_user_provider stateless: true refresh_jwt: check_path: /api/v1/auth/refresh`

I added same firewall for an Admin part but with another path:
`/api/admin/auth/refresh`
Also I added a route to ./config/routes.yaml:
`api_admin_refresh_token: path: /api/admin/auth/refresh`
When I try to send a query through Swagger, Symfony returns an error, stating that there is no Controller associated with a path /api/admin/auth/refresh.

Reading documentations and asking ChatGPT have not solved the problem.

Are there any chances to make this thing work?